# attr_accessible for Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, attr-accessible

Hello I need to use attr_accessible or something like that.And I am new on Ruby On Rails

That is my `post.rb` file

```
    class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :comments

  attr_accessible :body, :title, :published, :author, :author_id
  belongs_to :author, :class_name => "AdminUser"


  validates_presence_of :body,:title
  scope :published, where(:published => true)

  def content
    MarkdownService.new.render(body)
  end

  def author_name
    if author
      author.name
    else
      "Nobody"
    end
  end


end
```

what can I do for attr_accesible thanks for your answers.

Comment: A simple Google search would have helped immediately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to use [`Strong Params`](http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/StrongParameters.html) for this:

```
#app/models/post.rb
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :comments
  belongs_to :author, :class_name => "AdminUser"

  validates_presence_of :body,:title
  scope :published, where(:published => true)

  def content
    MarkdownService.new.render(body)
  end

  def author_name
    if author
      author.name
    else
      "Nobody"
    end
  end


end

#app/controllers/posts_controller.rb
def new
    @post = Post.new
end

def create
    @post = Post.new(post_params)
end

private

def post_params
    params.require(:post).permit(:body, :title, :published, :author, :author_id)
end
```

Comment: ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError in Admin::PostsController#update
I'm getting this error stil,its include for create post too...

Comment: ` def create
    @post = Post.new(post_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @post.save
        format.html { redirect_to @post, notice: 'Post was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @post }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'new' }
        format.json { render json: @post.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end ` create method

Answer (score 0):

Rails4 uses strong parameters rather than attr_accessibles.

For more info visit [doc](http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/StrongParameters.html)

Comment: I did everything about strong paramters but when I try create post ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError its says forbidden what can I do know